# Logstash reads data from stdin but not from file

Tags: json, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I have a JSON log file with only one line in it:

```
{"@timestamp":"2016-06-02T13:56:49.235+00:00","thread_name":"qtp485047320-228","level":"ERROR","host":"domain.com","class":"MyClass","url":"/my-url","ip":"12.122.122.122","message":"Exception caught by exception handler.","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36","stacktrace":"com.test.exceptions.NotFoundException: NotFoundException for parameter [12345678-1234]. Message: url was not found by service.]"}
```

And this is my logstash.conf file:

```
input {
     # stdin {}
    file {
      path => "/Users/me/Applications/logstash-2.3.1/examples/json_input.1.log"
      start_position => "beginning"
    }
}
filter {

    json{
        source => "message"
    }

    geoip {
        source => "ip"
        target => "geoip"
    }
}
output {
    stdout { 
        codec => rubydebug 
    }
    elasticsearch { 
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "logstash-app-errors"
    }
}
```

As you can see, at the input section I used stdin (in comment now) and later on, I changed to read the data from file.
The problem is that when I use the stdin and paste the json data (1 line) everything works great and I see the data in elasticSearch, but when I change it to file, nothing happens...
I also added `--debug` param to logstash execution command `./logstash agent -f logstash.conf --debug` but couldn't see anything suspicious in debug output.
What am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked your permissions? How did you install/run logstash. Logstash as a service runs with the logstash user. this user would not be able to access log files located in your home folder. Unfortunately, the file input will not report this error. Move your logfile to a different location (e.g. /var) or (as test) use chmod 777 or something to give everyone access to your file.

Comment: thank you @pandaadb, but it didn't work for me.It's not logstash as a service + earlier today i was able to read from that file.
I moved the file to /var/log and it didn't help, also tries sudo ./logstash without success...

Comment: one more thing - I'm deleting the .sincedb before each try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue - if the input file has only one line of data, you should add an empty new line.
That resolved my issue. can't believe I spent so much time on that one...

**Edit:**
Opened an issue to elastic, you can follow the issue status [here](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/5481)

Comment: I think its because the default line delimiter is "\n", so when its only one line there is no "\n" but EOF. I think that's the reason for the bug.

Comment: you might want to raise it with logstash if it's a bug :)

Comment: just wrote them :)